# Controlled rendering of contents of Tabs in angular material tabs

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular6

I am using Angular Material tab group.

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First"> <app-home> </app-home> </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> <app-info> </app-info> </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"><app-details> </app-home> </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

In `ngOnInit(){}` of each component I am calling one or more APIs and when my **app-component** renders tab group. contents of all tabs are getting loaded asynchronously, for this, all the APIs of all components are getting called. which is degrading efficiency.

I want to control rendering of contents of tabs so that only the selected tab is rendered. by this I can stop all other APIs from being called unnecessarily.

Can anyone help me by guiding to an appropriate event or technique to achieve this?

Comment: don't call all API on ngonInit by default load first tab group and call only that API on ngoninit whereas on every tab click call other APIs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another approach that is useful if you want to refresh the tab content when tab changed is to use ng-template with matTabContent. Example,

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="A">
    <ng-template matTabContent> Content of tab A </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="B">
    <ng-template matTabContent> Content of tab B </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Indeed i have done the same thing and to upgrade to angular 6 for that.

Comment: Very clean approach to force refresh on subtabs. Thanks. Works in angular 9.

Comment: It's working with Angular 14 just fine. It's an excellent approach to re-render the content.

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onTabClick($event)"
```

**TS**

```
public onTabClick(event: any): void { // clicked tab can be get using event.index
    // load data for the clicked tab
}
```